# Web Analytics for Platform with Custom Events

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, saas, platform, web-analytics

I'm building a platform that produces websites.  Think wordpress.com as a similar example.  Each site is going to be a subdomain of my domain like abc.mydomain.com or xyz.mydomain.com.

I have a few requirements for analytics of which I haven't been able to meet all of:

1. I would like to be able to see both stats for individual sites and aggregate stats for all sites.
2. I would like to track custom events, like how many contributions users have made.
3. I would like support for any number of subdomains.
4. I would like to be able to give my customers limited access to see the data only their site.
5. I would like to be able to set this all up in an automated way, ideally via an API, when a new site is created.

I know with Google Analytics you can create filters and profiles, which might solve 3) and/or 4) but I don't think this is exposed via the API AND I believe there is a limit on profiles of 50.

Also if I can't satisfy 4) I probably can't use Google Analytics at all as my clients would likely want to use it, and I don't think you can run two GA trackers at the same time.  That said, I would happily sacrifice 4) if the others were met as clients could still use their own GA account.

Of course I can just build a cron script to parse the various DBs and log files, but I'm hoping not to reinvent the wheel.   Plus I would miss out on all the nice graphs and extras that most services have.

Any platform developers have any insight here?

Thanks.

Comment: No SaaS folks out there with analytics experience?

Comment: We're looking at pretty much the same setup. But we haven't found a good pre-built solution either.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try youcalc.com, they have readymade analytics apps based on google analytics api, and you can download their tool for customizing existing apps, or even create new ones.

Comment: Thanks Charles.  I'll check them out.  So I guess the idea would be that I would use Google Analytics and somehow encode information about my events and which subdomains they're happening for, and then I could filter data in YouCalc based on that custom data?

Answer (score 0):

The question [Can I use the same Google Analytics tag for a blog subdomain of my site as the main site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533835/can-i-use-the-same-google-analytics-tag-for-a-blog-subdomain-of-my-site-as-the-ma) has a solution with Google Analytics that fits several of your requirements, but not all.